# Setting a dynamic timezone in yii2

Tags: php, timezone, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Does anyone know how to set a dynamic timezone for each user?
If the timezone is stored in database, how do i get it from db and set it at runtime so that i dont need to set it everytime in my codes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an example how to do it assuming timezone is stored as string in column `timezone` in `users` table. Add this to your application config:

```
'on beforeRequest' => function () {        
    $user = Yii::$app->user->identity;
    if ($user && $user->timezone) {
        Yii::$app->setTimeZone($user->timezone);
    }
},
```

This code will run before request and set timezone depending on specific user. Of course you can move it to separate class and call it from here.

**Official docs:**

- [setTimeZone()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-application.html#setTimeZone%28%29-detail)
- [date_default_timezone_set() native PHP function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out since yesterday though.
Hope it helps other users

Comment: @user2707590 You can also accept an answer in this case.

Comment: `on beforeRequest` is triggered just after `yii\base\Application::bootstrap`. isn't that too early to expect a user identity to be loaded?